# Creación y Borrado de tablas con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, tablas

Necesito ayuda, me explico, he creado un .html y un .js, en el html he puesto 2 botones (añadir y quitar), un `input` y un `div` (donde va a entrar todo lo que salga del .js). El caso es que no tengo idea porque no funciona el código. La función es que debes colocar un numero en el `input`, darle a añadir y que se añada la tabla de multiplicar del numero que colocaste. Los `div` son importantes para saber que elemento voy a añadir y quitar.

```js
var caja = document.getElementById("caja");

function añadir() {
// Creación de elementos
var diver = document.createElement("DIV")
var tabla   = document.createElement("table");
var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");
var x = document.getElementById("texto1").value;
var hilera = document.createElement("td");//tabla de fila
celda = document.createElement("th");//tabla de cabecera
//texto de cabecera
textoCelda = document.createTextNode('Tabla '+x);
//Creamos la familia Tblbody/hilera/celda/textoCelda
celda.appendChild(textoCelda);
hilera.appendChild(celda);
tblBody.appendChild(hilera);

//Bucle for
for(y=1;y<=10;y++){//Con que numero se multiplica la tabla de multiplicar
      celda = document.createElement("tr");

      textoCelda = document.createTextNode(x+' x '+y+' = '+(x*y));
      //Familia hilera/celda/textocelda
      celda.appendChild(textoCelda);
      hilera.appendChild(celda);
    }
//Familia caja/tabla/diver/tblbody/hilera
tblBody.appendChild(hilera);
diver.appendChild(tblBody);
tabla.appendChild(diver);
caja.appendChild(tabla)
}
function quitar() {
    
   
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<title>Ejercicio 2</title>



</head>
<body>
<h2>Ejercicio de añadir o retirar tablas de multiplicar</h2>
<script src="añadiroquitar.js"></script> <!--Link con el .js-->
<input type="text" id="texto1"><br><br><!--Entrada de texto donde se coloca el número-->
<button onclick="añadir()">Añadir</button><!--Botón añadir, para añadir la tabla de multiplicar-->
<button onclick="quitar()">Quitar</button><!--Botón quitar, para quitar una tabla de multiplicar-->
<br><br>
<div id="caja"></div><!--Aquí se exportarán los datos del .js-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. Ademas de agregar mas información, a simple vista el código parece funcionar correctamente. ¿que es exactamente lo que no funciona?

Comment: a ver si entendi la idea es ingresar en un input un numero al presionar añadir mostrara la tabla de multiplicar de dicho numero y al presionar quitar lo oculta ?

Comment: Lo remueve, como no entendía muy bien la lógica que necesitaba, tuve que llamar a un ingeniero, pero muchas gracias!

Comment: Te recomiendo asignarle un ID a la división `diver.id=document.getElementById("texto1").value;` para luego poder eliminar su contenido

Answer (score 0):

No sé el motivo por el que dices que tu código no funciona, quizas sea por algo que no hayas añadido en la pregunta. He añadido una "id" al div que contiene la tabla y utilizo esa "id" para eliminar el div con dicho número.

```js
var caja = document.getElementById("caja");

function añadir() {
// Creación de elementos
var diver = document.createElement("DIV");
var tabla   = document.createElement("table");
var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");
var x = document.getElementById("texto1").value;
diver .setAttribute("id", "Div "+x);
var hilera = document.createElement("td");//tabla de fila
celda = document.createElement("th");//tabla de cabecera
//texto de cabecera
textoCelda = document.createTextNode('Tabla '+x);
//Creamos la familia Tblbody/hilera/celda/textoCelda
celda.appendChild(textoCelda);
hilera.appendChild(celda);
tblBody.appendChild(hilera);

//Bucle for
for(y=1;y<=10;y++){//Con que numero se multiplica la tabla de multiplicar
      celda = document.createElement("tr");

      textoCelda = document.createTextNode(x+' x '+y+' = '+(x*y));
      //Familia hilera/celda/textocelda
      celda.appendChild(textoCelda);
      hilera.appendChild(celda);
    }
//Familia caja/tabla/diver/tblbody/hilera
tblBody.appendChild(hilera);
diver.appendChild(tblBody);
tabla.appendChild(diver);
caja.appendChild(tabla)
}
function quitar() {
   var x = document.getElementById("texto1").value;
   var div = document.getElementById("Div " + x);
   if( div != null )   div.remove();       
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<title>Ejercicio 2</title>



</head>
<body>
<h2>Ejercicio de añadir o retirar tablas de multiplicar</h2>
<script src="añadiroquitar.js"></script> <!--Link con el .js-->
<input type="text" id="texto1"><br><br><!--Entrada de texto donde se coloca el número-->
<button onclick="añadir()">Añadir</button><!--Botón añadir, para añadir la tabla de multiplicar-->
<button onclick="quitar()">Quitar</button><!--Botón quitar, para quitar una tabla de multiplicar-->
<br><br>
<div id="caja"></div><!--Aquí se exportarán los datos del .js-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola iñigo, gracias por aportar. Sin embargo para que una respuesta sea de buena calidad ha de explicar qué habia mal en el planteamiento de la pregunta y como el codigo que muestras funciona. Mira [answer] para más info y el [tour] para aprnder como funciona este sitio. Un saludo y bienvenido

Comment: Lo que tenía le funcionaba todo, por lo que no hay nada que comentar. Sólo he añadido la función de quitar.

Comment: pero lee los enlaces que te pasé y mejora la respuesta

Comment: Ya lo he leido y no veo eso que comentas.

Comment: Primero sobre la pregunta esta el que no está muy claro su problema. Dice que *"no tengo ni idea de por que no funciona el codigo"* en vez de dar la explicacion oportuna sobre los errores que encuentra. Respecto a tu respuesta, en el punto *"Contesta la pregunta"* explica como  aportar la solucion a l problema que el usuario pide pero tambien pudiendo proponer evitar el uso de algo. Y que *"La brevedad es aceptable pero respuestas robustas son las mejores."*. Mira tambien [¿Por qué he recibido un voto negativo? (solo codigo en la respuesta)](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/15855)

Comment: Gracias por el punto negativo, esto hace que se me quiten las ganas de ayudar a nadie ; )

Comment: Las ganas de ayudar, deberian ser independientes a lo que los demás piensan. Por supuesto motiva o desmotiva pero te sugiero que no lo tengas mucho en cuenta. **sobre todo** porque los votos negativos son anonimos y **no sabes** si fui yo u otra persona. Un saludo

Comment: Los votos, por otro lado, son revertibles, puedes votar algo negativo y luego deshacer el voto cuando la publicación (pregunta o respuesta) mejora

Comment: Y, por terminar de aclarar, un voto negativo no es a una persona, sino a una publicación en concreto. No te lo debes tomar como algo personal, simplemente analiza el porqué has podido recibir un voto negativo, y trata de mejorar el post en consecuencia.